# Way to find the valid test method parameters for the V93K platform?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am adding a quality check into my test interface that compares the test method parameters passed to the valid parameters defined in the test method library.  I found some code that works to return the valid parameters, but it is destructive in that it inserts empty test methods into the flow.

```
valid_params = test_methods.v93k.send(test_method_params[:test_method]).instance_variables.grep(/^\@[A-Z]/).map { |p| p.to_s.delete('@').to_sym }
```

Is there a way to simply query the test method library for the valid test method parameters for a particular test method?  I looked [here](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/) but didn't see anything.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YMMV on other platforms, but for the V93K, you can call `test_methods.<library>.definitions` to return a Hash which contains all the info supplied by a library definition like this - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods

The built in-libraries are defined in the same way, so here is an example:

```
(byebug) test_methods.dc_tml.definitions[:general_pmu]
{:class_name=>"GeneralPMU", :pinlist=>[:string, "@"], :force_mode=>[:string, "VOLT", ["VOLT", "CURR"]], :force_value=>[:force_mode, 3.8], :spmu_clamp=>[:force_modeb, 0], :precharge=>[:string, "OFF", ["ON", "OFF"]], :precharge_voltage=>[:voltage, 0], :settling_time=>[:time, 0], :tester_state=>[:string, "CONNECTED", ["CONNECTED", "DISCONNECTED", "UNCHANGED"]], :termination=>[:string, "OFF", ["ON", "OFF"]], :measure_mode=>[:string, "PPMUpar", ["PPMUpar", "PPMUser", "SPMUser"]], :relay_switch_mode=>[:string, "DEFAULT(BBM)", ["DEFAULT(BBM)", "BBM", "MBB", "PARALLEL"]], :ppmu_clamp_low=>[:voltage, 0], :ppmu_clamp_high=>[:voltage, 0], :output=>[:string, "None", ["None", "ReportUI", "ShowFailOnly"]], :test_name=>[:string, "passLimit_uA_mV"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a V93K test method library is described [here](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods), and the answer is to query the test method library itself, rather than the approach above.

```
# Given that the test method library is the variable tml
valid_params = tml.definition[test_method_params[:test_method].to_sym].ids.reject { |p| p.is_a? Symbol }
```

This code yields the same information and does not create empty parameter sets.

thx

Comment: updated code to exclude all Symbols which handles all corner cases (e.g. limit IDs) for our version of the V93K test method library.  The exclusion of all Symbols would not work in general.